# @fontface anomoly in all Windows browsers

Tags: windows, operating-system, font-face

I have come across a very strange anomonly when use the Caviar Dreams (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Caviar-Dreams) font from FontSquirell.

It renders perfectly on all Mac based browsers (FF, Safari & Chrome) but when I try and view it on any Windows based browser (FF, Chrome, Safari & of course IE) I get a very strange "blob" on the top of the letter "D" when it is capitalized.

I've never had this kind of problem before so it's giving me a bit of a headache.

Any ideas what the problem might be and/or a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rendering problem, and it will vary from one Windows configuration to another. For example, it will change if ClearType is turned on or off.

There are ways for font designers to embed 'hints' so rendering engines can avoid this problem, but that font may not have such hints.